# TensorFlow gradients: Getting unnecessary 0.0 gradients by tf.gradients

Tags: tensorflow, embedding, word-embedding, gradient

Let's suppose I have the following variable

> embeddings = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform(dtype=tf.float32,shape =
>   [self.vocab_size, self.embedding_dim], minval=-0.001, maxval=0.001))
>
> sent_1 = construct_sentence(word_ids_1)
>
> sent_2 = construct_sentence(word_ids_2)

Where `construct_sentence` is a method of obtaining a sentence representation based on the placeholders `word_ids_1` and `word_ids_2`

Let's suppose I have some loss:

> loss = construct_loss(sent_1, sent_2, label)

Now, when I try to get the gradients using:

> gradients_wrt_w = tf.gradients(loss, embeddings)

Instead of getting only the gradients with respect to the specific variables involved in `construct_sentence` and `construct_loss`, I get the gradients of every embedding in the variable `embeddings` (the gradients being 0 for those embeddings that are not involved in the loss & sentence representations).

**How can I get the gradients wrt variables I am only interested in?**

Moreover, I get repetitions of some variables (with the same value) because of the partial derivatives involved.  Since embeddings is a 2D Variable I can't do a simple lookup like this:

> tf.gradients(loss, tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, word_ids))

This introduces a huge performance slow-down, since I am working with large number of word embeddings and I want to take the derivative only wrt some word embeddings per time.

Moreover, I am getting a lot of duplicate gradients (because of the partial derivatives) and I tried using the  tf.AggregationMethod but that didn't work out.

Comment: Perhaps you can try making you embeddings variables vocab_size number of variables followed by a concat?

Comment: Did you try to define `embeddings` using `Trainable=False` in the constructor? See: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable#initializer

Comment: @mikkola That doesn't work.

Comment: @suharshs How would that help? It will lead to the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do
`tf.gradients(loss, tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, word_ids))`, 
but you can directly do `tf.gradients(loss, embeddings)` and this will give you a `tf.IndexedSlices` object containing only the gradients of affected word ids.

Regarding the aggregation of gradients corresponding to repetitive word ids, this is automatically done when calling `optimizer.apply_gradients`, but you can reproduce this using the `tf.unsorted_segment_sum` and `tf.unique` as follows:

```
embedding_table = tf.random_uniform((10, 5))
word_ids = tf.placeholder(shape=(None), dtype=tf.int32)
temp_emb = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding_table, word_ids)
loss = tf.reduce_sum(temp_emb, axis=0)

g = tf.gradients(loss, embedding_table)[0].values
repeating_indices = tf.gradients(loss, embedding_table)[0].indices # This is the same as word_ids.

unique_indices, idx_in_repeating_indices = tf.unique(repeating_indices)

agg_gradients = tf.unsorted_segment_sum(g,
                                        idx_in_repeating_indices,
                                        tf.shape(unique_indices)[0])

sess = tf.Session()
unique_indices_v, agg_gradients_v, _ = \
    sess.run([unique_indices, agg_gradients, loss],
         feed_dict={word_ids: np.array([6, 1, 5, 1, 1, 5])})


print(unique_indices_v)
print(agg_gradients_v)
```

giving for the above example:

```
[6 1 5]

[[1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [3. 3. 3. 3. 3.]
 [2. 2. 2. 2. 2.]]
```